# MS SQL Not Like Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one a list of students and one with a list of restaurants.  The people table has PK that is contained within the restaurants table as an FK.  The restaurant table contains the days the students like to eat out at restaurants (along with restaurants they eat at).  I'm trying to find the students who do not like to eat at the restaurant on Monday.  I tried using the query below, but it lists all of the students and not the ones that don't eat out on Monday.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SName   
FROM Dinner AS D
INNER JOIN Student AS S ON D.SID = S.SID    
WHERE DinnerDay NOT LIKE 'Monday'
GROUP BY SName
```

Comment: Consider using a `where not exists` query. Also, using both `distinct` and `group by` is unnecessary: both return unique `SName`. If you are aggregating (sum, avg etc), use `group by`, if you are only interested in returning unique values, use `distinct`.

Comment: Okay, tried the below, but it doesn't like the NOT EXISTS syntax :SELECT DISTINCT SName
FROM Dinner AS D
    INNER JOIN Student AS S
 ON D.SID = S.SID
WHERE DinnerDay NOT EXISTS 'Monday'

Comment: Why are you not using '<>' in place of 'NOT LIKE' ? Your NOT EXISTS syntax is wrong. In case you still want to use 'NOT LIKE' then use 'NOT LIKE 'Monday%'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT SName
FROM    Student AS S
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT      NULL
                        FROM        Dinner AS D
                        WHERE       DinnerDay = 'Monday'
                                AND D.SID = S.SID 
                    )
```

Comment: I tried that syntax, but it didn't return any results.

Comment: I made a small mistake, please see edit. You already have an answer, but it never hurts to have alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can use student table and a subquery. The subquery is the distinct list of all students that dine on Monday, then run a left outerjoin of student and subquery b where b.SID is null;

```
select S.SName from Student as S 
Left Outer Join 
(select Distinct S2.SID from Student as S2 Inner Join Dinner as D on S2.SID=D.SID where D.DinnerDay='Monday') as tbMonStd
on S.SID=tbMonStd.SID
where tbMonStd.SID IS NULL
```

The Subquery gives you the list of all students attached to Monday. The left outerjoin and the last where clause gives you the students not found in Monday list

Comment: Thanks, this one worked.  I just need to break down the syntax to understand it.  Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SName   
FROM Dinner AS D
INNER JOIN Student AS S ON D.SID = S.SID    
WHERE DinnerDay <> 'Monday'
```

Try using <>

Comment: <> doesn't appear to fix it, but got the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The Inner Join will remove rows that do not match on joining conditions.  So you could have students that never eat out an any restaurant, as written the inner join will eliminate these students. Instead you should use a left join, which will return null.

You also did a `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY`. This is removing duplicates twice.  You only need to do one of these.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN (D.ID IS NOT NULL)
                      THEN S.SName
                END
FROM Student AS S
LEFT JOIN Dinner AS D ON S.SID = D.SID AND D.DinnerDay = 'Monday'
```

This will return NULL for `D.ID` if the Student does not eat on Monday, or never eats out at any restaurant.  The case statement checks if `D.ID IS NOT NULL`, if so it returns `S.SName`.  This select is `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.